# How to preserve hypertext links while pasting in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

In Ubuntu 12.04, when cutting and pasting text from a web browser into LibreOffice, any hypertext links on the text are properly formatted and preserved.

But in Ubuntu 14.04, only the text is copied. All the hypertext links are lost. (Though cutting and pasting within LibreOffice preserves the links).

Is there anything I can do to restore the 12.04 cut-and-paste behavior in 14.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to preserve hyperlinks. This would bring a Paste Special dialog box, select *HTML (HyperText Markup Language)* and press the *Ok* button. Doing so would paste the text while preserving the hyperlinks.

[image: Paste Special dialog]

If you are not a keyboard person, you can also access it using the *Edit* menu → *Paste Special*.